# Matlab | Attempted to access x(0); index must be a positive integer or logical

Tags: matlab

im  trying to make a code for my hemowork using matlab, but already i have this error  `Attempted to access x(0); index must be a positive
integer or logical.` 
so this is my code :

```
Ax=0;
Ay=1.5;
Bx=40;
By=0;
Cx=0;
Cy=-1.5;
for t = 0:0.01:1
  x(t)=((1-t).^2)*Ax+2*t*(1-t)*Bx+(t.^2)*Cx;
   y(t)=((1-t).^2)*Ay+2*t*(1-t)*By+(t.^2)*Cy; 
end
```

if i change the values of `t = 1:1:100` the code work but i need this values ' t = 0:0.01:1 ` 
how to do that ? thanks

Comment: As the error message suggests, make it positive integer or logical. Hint: Use a different variable for indexing.

Comment: Please, get a MATLAB tutorial. This is as basic as it gets. There is no `x(0)` in MATLAB, and nor there is `x(0.01)` which would be your second option. Indexes (locations on an array) `must be a positive integer or logical`. Saying `x(0.01)` is like saying "grab the 5.42th chair". Not possible.

Comment: @AnderBiguri true, unless you define a range using a colon operator, `x(0.01:0.01)` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, indices in MATLAB start from 1. YOu are trying to keep index as 0, so the error is popping out. If you want to start from 0, you define an other variable and run loop along the indices of this variable. Check the below code:

```
Ax=0;
Ay=1.5;
Bx=40;
By=0;
Cx=0;
Cy=-1.5;
t = 0:0.01:1 ;
for i = 1:length(t)
    x(i)=((1-t(i)).^2)*Ax+2*t(i)*(1-t(i))*Bx+(t(i)^2)*Cx;
    y(i)=((1-t(i)).^2)*Ay+2*t(i)*(1-t(i))*By+(t(i)^2)*Cy;
end
```

As you are in MATLAB, note that, you can vectorize your code. Once you understand the basics of MATLAB, you try to vectorize the code.

```
%% Vectorized
x=((1-t).^2).*Ax+2*t.*(1-t)*Bx+(t.^2)*Cx;
y=((1-t).^2).*Ay+2*t.*(1-t)*By+(t.^2)*Cy;
```